# How can I make homebrew's cmake to use system clang

Tags: macos, cmake, clang

OS: MacOS 12.4

Installed cmake with

```
brew install cmake
```

cmake version 3.23.3

Installed clang with

```
xcode-select --install
```

clang++ version is 13.1.6

Trying to build ccls:

```
git clone https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls.git
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
```

And getting following output

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindClang.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Clang", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Clang" with any of
  the following names:

    ClangConfig.cmake
    clang-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Clang" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Clang_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Clang"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/umed/projects/MaskRay/ccls/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/umed/projects/MaskRay/ccls/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Is there anyway to make brew's cmake work with system clang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not correct. CMake uses the system clang successfully, but it can't find clang libraries required by the project.

The [Build](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/Build) manual lists the requirements, one of them is

- Clang+LLVM headers and libraries, version >= 7

You get errors because you have not provided that dependency.

```
brew install llvm@13
```

Comment: Already installed, this doesn't help cmake to find clang libraries

Comment: I had to run couple more commands `brew remove cmake`, `brew link llvm@13` and `brew install cmake`. That fixed the issue. Thank you!